# Lost session in my hosting (laravel)

Tags: laravel, session, server, hosting

My project is running on Server X. It has a login form.
When I input correctly username and password, click Login button, it will redirect to List screen. I cloned code to my local and it is running correctly.
But when I pull code to Server Y, maybe it was lost session. I input correctly username and password in login form but when I click button login, it can't redirect to List screen. It backed to Login Screen again.
I checked session status on server: its enabled. In this case, 
what it problem?

Comment: Have you changed the url params in the env file

Comment: @Marcus yes I changed

Comment: What are you using as your session driver?